# Classification with undefined classes

Tags: classification

I have been studying different topics in Statistics and Machine Learning, and while studying Confidence Intervals and Power analysis, a question came up:

We want to classify data with 3 features (X, Y, Z) as belonging to 3 possible intervals (multiclass classification):

Interval 1 data belonging to [0, A]
Interval 2 data belonging to [A, B]
Interval 3 data belonging to [B, 100].

Questions:
1) The boundaries A and B are not set in stone. A can be any number in the interval [25, 35], and B is any number in [60 , 70]. How do we set up the problem of deciding the values of A and B?, Should we try to answer Questions 1 and 2 together?

2) How many training data do I need (in each interval) to have enough confidence that we have enough data to learn a good classifier?

Many thanks for your help...